# AJAX Enabled WCF Service

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Is it possible to define more then one function in AJAX Enabled WCF Service ?
For instance:

```
[OperationContract]
    public string GreetUser(string uname)
    {
        return "Hello " + uname;
    }
 public string DeleteUser(string uname)
    {
        return "Hello " + uname;
    }
```

Comment: Yes. Just put the `OperationContract` on `DeleteUser`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an `[OperationContract]` above `DeleteUser`.

Note that you cannot overload a function/method using WCF Services.  The names have to be unique.  You can change the OperationContract Name attribute to fix overloaded functions/methods.

Comment: Not really an answer when you're only commenting on someone elses comment

Comment: @reach4thelasers: Certainly not the fault of `user1367934` that `vcsjones` decided to write a comment instead of an answer...

Comment: +1: Welcome to SO, user1367934. I'll remove the "vcsjones is right" part. That kind of reference doesn't work well with the Q/A format of SO (unless it's adequately linked, which in this case it isn't).